# Strange PUT error when uploading to S3 with Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless

I used [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com) to create an S3 bucket and Lambda functions for uploading a file.

In my "Resources" section I have the following to create the S3 bucket:

```
UploadBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: ${self:custom.s3BucketName}
    AccessControl: Private
    CorsConfiguration:
      CorsRules:
        - AllowedMethods:
          - PUT
          - HEAD
          AllowedOrigins:
          - "*"
          AllowedHeaders:
          - "*"
```

For some reason, every time I executed the file upload, the PUT request generated a

> "403 Forbidden"

So I started manually editing the CORS configuration XML directly in the S3 console when suddenly and inexplicably it started working.  Out of curiosity, I restored the CORS configuration back to the original manually and it still worked.  I re-deployed using the `sls deploy` command and it continues to work.

I'm curious why it is working all of a sudden and, more importantly, what I can do to make sure I don't run into this again.